# Linux Connect system call

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I've been looking for function prototype of connect system call so that I can hook into it. But I couldn't find anything online. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Kernel Version : 3.16

Comment: `ptrace` is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connect` system call is implemented in `net/socket.c`.
(For hysterical raisins, it is multiplexed through the `socketcall` system call.)